# What does "main module does not need module" actually mean?

Tags: go, dependencies

I have a [dependency](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang) in my go.sum which has a vulnerability. I'm trying to determine if we are affected.

The go.mod has the up to date version, but the go.sum lists many other earlier vulnerable versions. I run `go mod why https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang` and `go mod why -m https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang` and `go mod graph | grep client_golang` and see slightly different outputs, the last being the most verbose.

I also see this message "main module does not need module". Well, yes I understand that the main module doesn't need it but clearly it's a dependency. Does that mean something else I'm not understanding?

Comment: Items in go.sum are not necessarily dependencies. Refer to the go.mod file instead.